# How to compile CoffeeScript just-in-time in vim?

Tags: vim, coffeescript

I can easily vsplit vim window into two(left and right).

How to config vim to:

- edit CoffeeScript in the left-window
- view compiled JavaScript result in the right-window
- view error message at the status-line

When I type in the left-window, the right-window and status-line should update JIT.

For example:

```
========================================================================
alert "hello"                | alert("hello");
alert "world                 | alert;
                             |
========================================================================
missing ", starting on line 2
```

Just like `http://coffeescript.org/` -> `Try CoffeeScript`.

Comment: I haven't seen anything like that, but I do know that the coffeescript Vim plugin does a syntax check and gives those warnings you might be looking for: https://github.com/kchmck/vim-coffee-script

Comment: vim-coffee-script does have the live preview feature similar to the coffeescript.org site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't just use vim for this, I use a combination of GNU screen, GNU source-highlight and GNU watch. However, you need to have the version of screen that has the vertical split patch.

After starting `screen`, I'll hit <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd><kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> to create a second shell, then use <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd><kbd>Shift+\</kbd> to create a vertical split, then <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> to swap over to the new split and <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd><kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd> to swap the split over to the new shell. In that shell, I run:

```
$ mkdir compiled
$ coffee -w -c -o compiled/ *.coffee &
```

That will run `coffee` in watch mode, which watches the source file (*.coffee) or folder for changes, and automatically recompiles changed *.coffee files and places the resulting .js files in the `compiled` folder.

Now, I will run `$ watch --color -n 1 colorize compiled/main.js` to display the contents of the compiled file I'm interested in, enabling ANSI colorized output.

That script file that I have called `colorize` is just a wrapper around `source-highlight` that automatically detects the language of the source file and applies appropriate syntax highlighting.

Then I use <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd><kbd>Ctrl+Tab</kbd> to move back over to the first split, and fire up `vim main.coffee` and start editing away.

As I edit the coffeescript file, the compiled changes show up on the right hand side.

Errors are a little trickier, as they get spit out from the background `coffee -w` job. They will show up, but sometimes the `watch` command will overwrite the errors, and sometimes the errors will mess up the screen. When that happens, a quick <kbd>Ctrl+L</kbd> to tell bash to redraw the screen fixes things up.

Hope that's of some help.

Comment: Very good idea, upvoted, but you don't need all that fancyness of `colorize` and `screen`. 

Just made it work here with `coffee -wco ./ *.coffee` on the background, `vim file.coffee` on one terminal window (gnome-terminal) and `watch -n 1 file.js` on another.

Comment: I'm not sure you can do a simple `watch -n 1 file.js`, unless you have a different version of watch than I do. Also, that won't give you any colorized output on the watched file.

Comment: Also, you *do* need screen if you're SSH'ing into a remote server that doesn't do X-forwarding (which I do).

Comment: You're very right. I'd never used `screen` before. Now I did and it's awesome. And works like a charm for ssh sessions. Thank you. (Also, I mistyped the command for `watch`, I did it with `watch -n 1 cat file.js`, but this is not so good as it seemed with a small file.)

Answer (score 0):

#### vimrc config

```
set autoread

aug coffee
    au!
    au BufNewFile,BufRead *.coffee      setf coffee.python
    au FileType coffee.python           setl makeprg=coffee\ -c\ %
    au FileType coffee.python           setl errorformat=Error:\ In\ %f\\,\ %m\ on\ line\ %l,
                                                       \Error:\ In\ %f\\,\ Parse\ error\ on\ line\ %l:\ %m,
                                                       \SyntaxError:\ In\ %f\\,\ %m,
                                                       \%-G%.%#
    au BufWritePost *.coffee            silent! make! | copen | redraw!
aug END
```

Note: If you like `JIT`, try **CursorHold** instead of **BufWritePost**.

#### open file

```
$ vim -O code.{coffee,js}
```

#### run ex command

```
:w
```